# can ffmpeg video bit rate option use a multiplier from a txt file as an argument?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, batch

I have a plain txt file containing a single number (either 1 or 2) and I wanna create a batch file that takes that number as a multiplier in `-b:v 3000k` so that the batch file will create a video with a bit rate of either 3000k or 6000k depending on the external multiplier. Is it possible to perform calculations on the value specified behind `-b:v`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. See https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html - Expression Evaluation.

your external multiplier as multiplier.txt:

```
2
```

ffmpeg.bat:

```
## Read file content into a variable:
set /p multiplier=<multiplier.txt

## Then use the variable as %multiplier%
ffmpeg.exe -i INPUT -b:v %multiplier%*3000k OUTPUT
```

Comment: your solution is probably correct, however, my multiplier txt file is located in `C:\MyProg\MP` and the bat file itself in `C:\MyProg\BAT`. How do I have to write the relative path in the `set /p` line?

Comment: Like this: `set /p multiplier=<"C:\MyProg\MP\multiplier.txt"`